# How does Java CompletionService manage multiple task submits?

Tags: java, concurrency, completion-service

I need to know how does Java handles when you submit more tasks than the current poolsize. I have the code below:

```
Executor executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2); //2 threads
CompletionService<MyCallable> serv = new ExecutorCompletionService<MyCallable>(executor);
for (int i=0; i<500; i++){
         serv.submit(new MyCallable(i));
}
```

Any clues if *submit* is a blocking call? or will it reject the tasks if the threads are all busy?

Thank you all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It maintains a queue of tasks, and `submit` returns as soon as the task is *added to the queue*.  It doesn't wait for a thread to start on the tasks.

Comment: Do you know when the submit would reject and fail?? the official source code of the ThreadPoolExecutor has a condition where it can fail and reject the tasks

Comment: @HernanZ The Javadoc for [`CompletionService#submit`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorCompletionService.html#submit(java.lang.Runnable,V)) tells you that it throws `RejectedExecutionException` if the task cannot be scheduled for execution.